# SwiftUI macOS respond to menu bar action from sub-view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view in my macOS app that needs to be notified when the user has pressed the undo and redo buttons in the menu bar. In the `AppDelegate`, I have IBActions that get triggered when the user presses the undo/redo button. The IBAction posts a notification using notification center, as shown below:

```
extension Notification.Name {

    static let undo = Notification.Name("undo")
    static let redo = Notification.Name("redo")
}

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBAction func menuBarUndo(_ sender: Any) {
        print("AppDelegate: pressed undo")
        nc.post(name: .undo, object: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func menuBarRedo(_ sender: Any) {
        print("AppDelegate: pressed redo")
        nc.post(name: .redo, object: nil)


    }

    let nc = NotificationCenter.default

    // applicationDidFinishLaunching and applicationWillTerminate not shown for brevity

}
```

In my `ContentView` I have a function that needs to be triggered when the user presses the undo/redo button. It needs to be triggered from within the `ContentView` because it relies on data contained within that view. How do I subscribe to the notification from within `ContentView` so I can trigger the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ContentView` in can be as below

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Demo for receiving notifications")
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .undo)) { _ in
            /// call undo action
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .redo)) { _ in
            /// call redo action
        }
    }
}
```